# Required device capabilitiesi

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

If i use accelerometer in my app should i add Required device capabilitiesi in info.plist and enter accelerometer ?if yes what should i add exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You should write code defensively and always "degrade" the app nicely.
For example, you should think of how you app will run if accelerometer is not present.

Have a look at the CMMotionManager class - in particular at its accelerometerActive property which returns a BOOL. Here is an example:

```
CMMotionManager *manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if(!manager.accelerometerAvailable) { 
  NSLog(@"Accelerometer not available");
} else { 
  manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0;
  NSOperationQueue *motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; 
  [manager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue: motionQueue withHandler:
    ^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error) { 
      NSLog(@"Accelerometer data: %@", [data description]);
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: you mean don't need to add anything to info.plist?and just check that device support accelerometer or not. what does happen if i don't check it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
  <array>
    <string>accelerometer</string>
  </array>
```

Further details in the  iOS Application Programming Guide (page 89, table 5-1).
You do not need to include this key if your app detects only device orientation changes.

Answer (score -1):

no you don't need to add anything to your info.plist.
Just make sure that your appDelegate implements protocol UIAccelerometerDelegate and then in your .m file just do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
 ...
 [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
 ....
}

- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration
{
     //your accelerometer code
}
```